# styled-components doesn't update Navlinks attributes properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

The `active` class on `Navlink` components does not update properly to show the correct active route.

Home Route
[image: Home Route]

Other Routes
[image: Bookmarks Route]
[image: About Me Route]

As you can see, the **Home** route is always shown *active*, and the inspect tools also show the same issue-

[image: inspect tool]

Here's the code sample-

```
// Header.tsx
<S.Navbar>
    <NavLink to='/'>Home</NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/bookmarks'>Bookmarks</NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/about-me'>About Me</NavLink>
</S.Navbar>

// App.tsx
<Route component={() => <h1>Home</h1>} path='/' exact />
<Route component={() => <h1>Bookmarks</h1>} path='/bookmarks' exact />
<Route component={() => <h1>About Me</h1>} path='/about-me' exact />
```

I'm using TypeScript. (if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add exact to your NavLinks. Home will always be set to active because it matches with the "/" path.

```
// Header.tsx
<S.Navbar>
    <NavLink to='/' exact>Home</NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/bookmarks' exact>Bookmarks</NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/about-me' exact>About Me</NavLink>
</S.Navbar>
```

Comment: I didn't know that **Navlink** also needs to have an `exact` prop. Thanks